# Run MVC Mock Test with Powermock in the Classpath

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, powermock

I have a really hard time setting up the test for a REST API in a project were PowerMock as already present.

The test looks something like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {RestServiceImpl.class})
@Import({RestServiceImpl.class})
public class CheckoutServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyFirstBean myFirstBean;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(this.mockMvc);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
       when(this.myFirstBean.doMagic()).thenReturn(42);

       this.mockMvc.perform(get("/some/path/and/stuff").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Depending on which versions I have in the classpath, I get different exceptions.

If I let PowerMock fetch Mockito on its own (it's a Maven build) I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
```

Examples for this are PowerMock 1.6.6, which fetches Mockito 1.10.19.

Most other combinations bring the above exception, too. However PowerMock 1.7.0RC2 with Mockito 2.4.0 brings this new exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.<init>(PowerMockMaker.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Of course I checked the [manual](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions), but neither of the combinations I tried worked for me.

I have Spring Boot 2.1.8  with Spring 5.1.9, if that makes a difference.

Has someone found a setup which makes all of these frameworks work together?